# Write extension function on Flow<T>.catch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I would like to modify the default Flow.catch function and always call a specific suspend function `logOutIfUserHasNoAccount()`. My current implementation is:

```
private suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.catchLoginError(action: suspend FlowCollector<T>.(Throwable) -> Unit): Flow<T> {
    logOutIfUserHasNoAccount()
    return catch(action)
}
```

My questions is: Is there any disadvantage that my Flow.catchLoginError function is also a suspend function? The default implementation of catch is:

```
// Not suspending
public fun <T> Flow<T>.catch(action: suspend FlowCollector<T>.(Throwable) -> Unit): Flow<T> { /* compiled code */ }
```

### Using

```
suspend fun login() = flow {

}.catchLoginError( e -> 
 // here it should call "logOufIfUserHasNoAccount" first
 doStuff(e)
```

}

Comment: Do you only want to log out if there's an error? As is, your function will always log out before Flow collection even begins.

Comment: In that case, my function is wrong. I only want to  logout if there is an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function when called immediately calls the logout function, and *then* returns a wrapped version of the original Flow that will catch errors when it is collected.

To logout only when errors occur, you should move the call inside the `catch` call's block. It doesn't need to be a suspend function either.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.catchLoginError(action: suspend FlowCollector<T>.(Throwable) -> Unit): Flow<T> = catch { error ->
    logOutIfUserHasNoAccount()
    action(error)
}
```